# how to used blazorise numeric edit group separating

Tags: c#, html, bootstrap-4, blazorise

I'm trying to use blazorise numeric edit group separating attribute. as it is said in it's documentation it should be possible to use it, but as I tried, it's not working.
I would appreciate it if you can help me to use blazorsie components to separate digits define thousands.
for example, when I'm entering value 12345678, it shows 12,345,678
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the code you tried an doesn't work?

Comment: <NumericEdit @bind-Value="@paymentDocumentCreateCommand.TotalPrice" GroupSeparator=","></NumericEdit>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NumericEdit`](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/numeric) component does not have a `GroupSeparator` parameter. The `GroupSeparator` parameter is on the [`NumericPicker`](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/numeric-picker) component:

```
<NumericPicker @bind-Value="@paymentDocumentCreateCommand.TotalPrice" GroupSeparator="," />
```

`NumericPicker` was added in Blazorise version `1.0.0`.

[NumericPicker](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/numeric-picker) vs [NumericEdit](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/numeric)

**Workaround:**

You can use the `TextEdit` component and apply a format when you convert the number to string.

```
<TextEdit @bind-Text="@TotalCost" />

<p>@_totalCost</p>

@code {
    private double _totalCost = 1234567890;

    private string TotalCost
    {
        get
        {
            return _totalCost.ToString("#,#");
        }
        set
        {
            _totalCost = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? 0 : double.Parse(value);
        }
    }
}
```

[Custom binding formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-binding-formats)

You can create a custom input component that does this conversion internally.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but here I got an error, which says :The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-Value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc. I couldn't solve it

Comment: ps: my blazorise component version is 0.9.3.4

Comment: `NumericPicker` does not exist in version `0.9.3.4`. It was added in version `1.0.0`. You need to update to a more recent version.

Comment: I'm using .net 5.0 and version 1.0.0 is not compatible :D. is there any other way?

Comment: Added a possible workaround in my answer.

Comment: I used TextEdit and TextChanged event.      <TextEdit Text="@totalPrice" TextChanged="@separate"></TextEdit>
    Task separate(string value)
            {
                totalPrice = string.Format("{0:#,0}", Convert.ToUInt64(value));
    
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }